# How to SELECT/Evaluate Column expression stored in the Table

Tags: sql

I have one problem in executing Dynamic SQL in one of my project.

I just want to extract one column from table where that column expression stored in table.

Example,

```
Id first_name last_name Full_name
1 X Y

Case When First_name = 'x' then first_name+Last_name Else last_name end
```

when I select the above table using

```
SELECT id,first_name,last_name,full_name
```

I am expecting the result as

```
Id first_name last_name Full_name
1 X Y 'XX'
```

But the below is the answere which am getting,

```
Id first_name last_name Full_name
1 X Y Case When First_name = 'x' then first_name+Last_name Else last_name end
```

Actually, I using dynamic query to evaluate the expression for each rows for that column to acheive generic framework to avoid changing the SPs everytime on any changes.

Could you please help me out on this case.

Please find my actual query

```
SELECT1 as [BATCH_ID],src.[SRC_REF_ID] as [SRC_REF_ID],dq.[XREF_DQ_ID] as 
[ID],dq.[DQ_CHECK_EXPRESSION] as [IS_DQ_PASSED],GETDATE() as 
[CREATED_DATE_TIME],'System' as [CREATED_USER] FROM  [SRC] src WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [DQ] dq WITH (NOLOCK)ON  src.customer    =   DQ.customer
```

the column [DQ_CHECK_EXPRESSION]  has value  'CASE WHEN ISNULL(src.REQS_ID,'') = '' THEN  'Y' ELSE 'N' END'
Thanks,
GopiK

Comment: It looks like your query is ending up as a literal string in your output.  Can you share the actual code with us?

Comment: Thanks for you help. SELECT 
 1 as [BATCH_ID],
 src.[SRC_REF_ID] as [SRC_REF_ID],
 dq.[XREF_DQ_ID] as [ID],
 dq.[DQ_CHECK_EXPRESSION] as [IS_DQ_PASSED],
 GETDATE() as [CREATED_DATE_TIME],
 'System' as [CREATED_USER]
 FROM  [SRC] src WITH (NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN [DQ] dq WITH (NOLOCK)
 ON src.customer = DQ.customer

 the column [DQ_CHECK_EXPRESSION] has value  as  'CASE WHEN ISNULL(src.REQS_ID,'') = '' THEN  'Y' ELSE 'N' END'.

Comment: Put this into your question please, formatted as code.